# Is there a type for an array of specific type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, types

If you want create some custom object like so:

```
{
    list: [],
    type: [String] || Array<String>
}
```

So that I can do a type check like if `var.type == Array<String> || var.type == [String]` ?

Comment: You should look into Typescript if you want static typing.

Comment: isArray a method given in js.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: @mukundpatel but how does that let you check for array restricted to a specific type?

Comment: Not possible in js. Typescript is best for it. Other wise create a closure structure. Use getter and setter for it.

Answer (score 0):

While I suggest using typescript if you need type safety, if you *must* use JS, you could create a function to check the array.

We can check if the item is an array, and that every element is of type string.

```js
let strArr = ["A", "B", "C"];
let numArr = [1, 2, 3];

function isString(val) {
  return (typeof val === "string");
}

function isStrArray(val) {
  return Array.isArray(val) && val.every(isString);
}

console.log("String array", isStrArray(strArr));
console.log("String array", isStrArray(numArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with (you pass the array for the first parameter, and the type you want to check the array items against as the second parameter, it should work for most objects):

```js
var checkArrayType = function checkArrayType (arr, type) {
  
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new Error('The argument "arr" must be an array!');
  }
  else if(type !== null && type !== undefined && typeof type != 'function') {
    throw new Error('The argument "type" must be a function, "null", or "undefined"!');
  }
  
  // 'null' and 'undefined' require a different check than the main one
  if(type === null || type === undefined) {
    return arr.every(function(e){
      return e === type;
    });
  }
  
  return arr.every(function(e){
    /* 
     * not using 'instanceof' because it would return 'true'
     * for cases like 'subObj instanceof Object'. 
     * ---------------------------------
     * using 'Object(e)' so that the check works for primitives, see:
     * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
     */
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(Object(e)) === type.prototype;
  });
  
};


console.log(checkArrayType([1,2,3,4], Number)); // true
console.log(checkArrayType(['hello', 10], String)); // false
console.log(checkArrayType([[1, 2.5], ['a', 'b']], Array)); // true
console.log(checkArrayType([null, null, null, null], null)); // true
console.log(checkArrayType([new String('hello'), new String('world')], Object)); // false

var Foo = function Foo(){};
console.log(checkArrayType([new Foo(), new Foo()], Foo)); // true

console.log(checkArrayType({a: null}, null)); // throws error
console.log(checkArrayType([], 'abc')); // throws error
```

BTW, it would be great if anyone could help me with that long comment inside of my `.every`, how would you deal with a comment that explains 2 different concepts (without making a separate variable for `Object(e)`) ?

Answer (score -3):

Potential answer?

You could make `type: [String]` and then when checking type,

```
if(var.type.constructor == Array){
    if(var.type[0] && var.type[0] == String){
        // type == [String]
    } else () {
        // check other types
    }
}
```

Comment: What if index 1 is not a string? This isn’t really type safe.